# preg_match понимает не все русские буквы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему может быть, что

```
preg_match('/^[а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $userName)
```

возвращает `true` для буквы "ПП","пп","УУ","еe","яя" и `false` для "тт", "уу","юю" и других?

Кодировка UTF-8. Php 5.2.17

Также я заметил, что `strlen($userName)`, например, для "пп" = 4, а для "уу" = 2.

П.С. При этом

```
preg_match('/^[_0-9A-Za-zА-Яа-пр-яЁё]+$/', $userName)
```

работает.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В PHP Регулярные выражения не работают с русскими буквами. Для работы с ними нужно использовать модификатор `/u`

> **u (PCRE_UTF8)**
>   Этот модификатор включает дополнительную функциональность PCRE, которая не совместима с Perl: шаблон и целевая строка обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки. Модификатор u доступен в PHP 4.1.0 и выше для Unix-платформ, и в PHP 4.2.3 и выше для Windows платформ. Валидность UTF-8 в шаблоне и целевой строке проверяется начиная с PHP 4.3.5. Недопустимая целевая строка приводит к тому, что функции preg_* ничего не находят, а неправильный шаблон приводит к ошибке уровня E_WARNING. Пятый и шестой октеты UTF-8 последовательности рассматриваются недопустимыми с PHP 5.3.4 (согласно PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); ранее они считались допустимыми.

[Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Пример:

```
preg_match( '/^([а-яА-ЯЁёa-zA-Z0-9_]+)$/u', $userName)
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало. А что конкретно делает этот модификатор?

Comment: Позволяет использовать символы с таблицы unicode

Answer (score 2):

На счет разного результата strlen - для utf-8 следует использовать [mb_strlen](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php).

Comment: Это происходит из за того,  что  strlen меряет сколько байт занимает строка, а каждый байт это один символ, но не в UTF. Т.к. 1байт это 256 значений, utf просто не влазит в этот порядок, по этому для записи кода UTF используется два байта, вот и получается что utf текст по размеру в два раза больше. А функция mb_strlen решает эту проблему