# Bash, regexp и кириллица

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash, кириллица

У нас есть **bash** скрипт, который работает на различных платформах (от старенького Debian GNU/Linux 5.0 (Linux 2.6.32.11, bash 3.2.39) до Red Hat 4.8.2 (Linux 3.10.0, bash 4.2.46)). Скрипт этот на входе (в качестве параметра или STDIN) принимает строку, которая содержит много всего.
Строка эта обрабатывается, лишнее - вырезается, итог вставляется в JSON-запрос и отправляется дальше. Но столкнулся с задачей, которую решить на данный момент не получается. А заключается она в следующем:

> Необходимо составить регулярное выражение, которое будет вырезать все
>   символы, кроме латиницы, кириллицы, чисел и знаков пунктуации.

И всё бы хорошо, в ряде ОС у нас кириллица в исходниках - воспринимается в штыки. Т.е. скрипт работает до тех пор - пока не появится необходимость его отредактировать/поправить. После попытки редактирования, из-за конструкции вида:

```
string=${string//[^0-9A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]/_};
```

(а именно из-за `А-Яа-яЁё`) сохранить открытый файл в том же `nano` - проблематично. Самое на мой взгляд логичное решение - заменить сами символы кириллицы - их кодами, но как? Попытки вида `\430-\44f` `\u430-\u44f` `\x430-\x44f` - не приносят успеха. При просмотре кодов hexdump-ом у нас картинка следующая:

```
printf 'abcd' | hexdump -C; exit 0;
$ ./test.sh
00000000  61 62 63 64                                       |abcd|
00000004

printf 'абвг' | hexdump -C; exit 0;
$ ./test.sh test
00000000  d0 b0 d0 b1 d0 b2 d0 b3                           |........|
00000008

printf %x "'а"; echo " "; printf %x "'я"; exit 0;
$ ./test.sh test
430
44f

printf %x "'a"; echo " "; printf %x "'z"; exit 0;
$ ./test.sh test
61
7a
```

Окончательно формирую свой вопрос:

> Какой вид должно иметь регулярное выражение (применимое по возможности в *чистой*
>   среде bash), уделяющее все символы, кроме латиницы, кириллицы, чисел и
>   знаков пунктуации, учитывая что диапазон символов кириллицы должен
>   быть записан в виде диапазона кодов символов, а не самих символов.

**Update #1**

Так - работает: `echo $string | perl -lpe 's/[^0-9A-Za-z\xDO\x90-\xD0\xBF\xD1\x80-\xD1\x8F]/_/g'`, но порождает зависимость от перла. За эту подсказку спасибо хабраюхеру [Shetani](http://habrahabr.ru/users/Shetani/)

**Обновление 2**

Правило:

```
string=${string//[^0-9A-Za-z\xDO\x90-\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80-\xd1\x8f\xd0\x81\xd1\x91]/_};
```

Ввод:

```
message_text='qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM абв..эюяАБВ..ЭЮЯ 1234567890~!@#$%^&*()_"`'"'";
string="<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>$message_text</body></html>";
```

Вывод:

> `__DOCTYPE_html__html__body_qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM__________________1234567890_________________body___html_`

Comment: Как насчет установить правильную (единую кодировку) для всех систем?

Comment: Это utf-8. Его и надо "вбивать" (кстати, IMHO от локализации не зависит и всюду должно работать (если фонты есть)).

Comment: Меня другое позабавило, есть куча машин с этим скриптом и похоже его вручную отдельно редактируют на каждой машине в том числе и на которых есть какая-то проблема с кодировкой из-за чего его не хотят сохранять корректно текстовые редакторы.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `[^0-9A-Za-z\p{Cyrillic}]`

Comment: `[^0-9A-Za-z\p{Cyrillic}]` - так пропускает вообще всё

Comment: Код не обязательно редактируют на каждой машине. Тут скорее принципиальный подход - из-за 2..3 символов в регулярке сорсов получать потенциальный геморрой - абсурд. Плюс подражает ряд зависимостей. Да, везде UTF-8.

Comment: @NikolayNikolaevich сделайте, пожалуйста, замену `s/./_/g` и скажите мне сколько прочерков получили на выходе для строки `абвг`

Comment: @NikolayNikolaevich сделайте update2 ответом, если Вас это не затруднит.

Comment: @ReinRaus - да, конечно, завтра только смогу отметить его как решение. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите по поводу кириллицы
[preg_match понимает не все русские буквы][1]


  [1]: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417568/preg-match-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B/417575#417575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге функция, которая режет всё лишнее и подготавливает строку к передаче в JSON выглядит у меня так:

```bsh
## Check existing application by app name, return string 'true' or 'false'
function checkAppExists() {
  ## $1 = (required) application name
  hash $1 2>/dev/null && echo "true" || echo "false";
}

## Prepare string for JSON
function prepareStringForJSON() {
  local string=$1;
  if [ $(checkAppExists "perl") == "true" ]; then
    # Step 0 - Split in single line (remove \r)
    # Step 1 - Remove all chars, except declared in regexp
    # Step 2 - Replace "\" => "\\"
    # Step 3 - Replace "/" => "\/"
    # Step 4 - Replace """ => "\""
    # Step 5 - Replace \n  => "\n"
    # Step 6 - Replace \t  => "\t"
    string=$(echo "$string" |\
    tr -d '\r' |\
    perl -pe 's/[^[[:space:]]\t\n~`'\''\.,\[\]\(\)\{\}@#\$%_\^&*:=\+;\|\"\-<>!\\\/0-9A-Za-z\xDO\x90-\xD0\xBF\xD1\x80-\xD1\x8F]//gs' |\
    perl -pe 's#\\#\\\\#gs' |\
    perl -pe 's#\/#\\\/#gs' |\
    perl -pe 's#\"#\\\"#gs' |\
    perl -pe 's#\n#\\n#gs' |\
    perl -pe 's#\t#\\t#gs');
  fi;
  echo "$string"; # Return result
}
```

Comment: Кстати :) Раз уж все равно используете перл - можете свернуть кодпойнты в `\p{Cyrillic}`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить кириллицу диапазонами `\xDO\x90-\xd0\xbf` и `\xd1\x80-\xd1\x8f` Ё `\xd0\x81` ё `\xd1\x91`

```
string=${string//[^0-9A-Za-z\xDO\x90-\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80-\xd1\x8f\xd0\x81\xd1\x91]/_};
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа (Ctrl+K).