# preg_match не работает с русскими буквами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему данный код не выводит 1 ?

```
$message = "Андрей";

if(preg_match('/^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$/', $message)){

    echo "1";   
}
```

Comment: /^[а-ярА-ЯёРЁa-zA-Z]+$/

Comment: Регулярка верная. Стоит обратить внимание на кодировку русского текста. Обычно `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` решает эти проблемы

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [preg\_match понимает не все русские буквы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417568/preg-match-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам надо разбирать строку в UTF-8, необходимо использовать модификатор `u`

> u (PCRE_UTF8) Этот модификатор включает дополнительную
>   функциональность PCRE, которая не совместима с Perl: шаблон и целевая
>   строка обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки. Недопустимая целевая строка
>   приводит к тому, что функции preg_* ничего не находят, а неправильный
>   шаблон приводит к ошибке уровня E_WARNING. Пятый и шестой октеты UTF-8
>   последовательности рассматриваются недопустимыми с PHP 5.3.4 (согласно
>   PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); ранее они считались допустимыми.

То есть в вашем случае:

```
preg_match('/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-ZёЁ]+$/u', $message)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня в таком варианте заработала:

```
$message = "Андрей";

 if(preg_match('/^[а-яА-Яa-zA-ZёЁ]+$/u', $message)){
      echo "1";   
}
```