# Отделить текст от цифр

Tags: php

Пробую отделить текст от цифр, но ничего не выходит (результат представленного ниже регулярного выражения пуст)

```
print_r(divide_sample('центр25'));

private final function divide_sample($sample_number)
{
    preg_match("/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)([0-9]+)/", $sample_number, $pieces);

    return $pieces;
}
```

Ожидаемый выход: `['центр', '25']`

Фиддл - http://tpcg.io/s5vdhO

Передаваться функции всегда будет или текстЧисло или числоТекст. Смешанных строк быть не может. Как быть? Может есть другие варианты - не регулярные выражения? Вопрос не дубликат. И название у вопроса реально удобнее выгуглить.

Comment: попробуйте preg_match_all только выражение разделите на ИЛИ `"/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)|([0-9]+)/"`. Хотя в таком случае по идее даже круглые скобки не нужны будут

Comment: @Mike вариант `"/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)|([0-9]+)/"` выдал - https://i.imgur.com/e30uJKz.png

Comment: Попробуйте `^(\D+)?(\d+)(\D+)?$`

Comment: @AlexChermenin - ошибка `"/(^(\D+)?(\d+)(\D+)?$)/"`

Comment: Похоже там скобки лишние :) `"/^(\D+)?(\d+)(\D+)?$/"` или просто `"/(\D+)?(\d+)(\D+)?/"`.

Comment: @n.osennij Не наблюдаю такого странного массива, особенно если указать что кодировка utf8 соответствующим флагом https://ideone.com/7J4n5L

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [preg\_match понимает не все русские буквы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417568/preg-match-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b)

Comment: @sanmai попробуй выгугли вопрос с таким названием

Comment: Автор, а проверьте выбранный ответ на таких данных "25центр" :Р

Comment: @Visman т.к. такой вариант крайне редкий 1 на 1000, наверное, решил использовать две разные функции. Если выбранная ничего не вернёт, то пропущу через другую. А два ответ выбрать нельзя.

Comment: @Visman думаете стоит выбрать другой ответ? Более универсальный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю свой вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
function divide_sample($str, $out = []) {
    preg_match_all('~(\d+)?(?(1)|\D+)~', $str, $arr);

    foreach ($arr[0] as $item) {
        ctype_digit($item) ? $out['int'] = $item : $out['txt'] = $item;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

В результате функция вернёт ассоциативный массив *$out* с ключами *int* и *txt*, в которых данные будут соответствовать их названиям.

Далее можно с помощью ф-ции extract() экспортировать этот массив в текущую область видимости, после чего в скрипте станут доступны переменные $int и $txt.

И даже если поменять в вызове функции *divide_sample()* местами текст с числом - значения этих переменных всё равно будут корректными. Примеры использования:

```
extract(divide_sample('25центр'));
echo $int . ' - ' . $txt . '<br />'; // 25 - центр

extract(divide_sample('центр25'));
echo $int . ' - ' . $txt;            // 25 - центр
```

Comment: @n.osennij я дополнил свой ответ.

Comment: не помешало бы ещё добавить trim()

Comment: зачем? В передаваемых на вход данных пробелов быть не должно.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в отсутствии юникодного флага: https://ideone.com/uWO8vT

```
<?php

$sample_number = 'центр25';
preg_match("/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)([0-9]+)/u", $sample_number, $pieces);
print_r($pieces);
```

Comment: Ответ не полон, почему, интересно, автор вопроса выбрал его как решение?

Comment: Потому что проблема в русских буквах.

Comment: @sanmai, я не про русские буквы, а про не полное решение поставленного вопроса.

Comment: @Visman, ну, я снова вопрос не дочитал до конца :(

Answer (score 2):

в копилку вариант:

```
 array_filter(preg_split("/(\d+)/",$str, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

если не будет строк вида `центр0`, то можно использовать прямо так. Если `0` будет встречаться, то callback-надо писать.

---

тест:

```
foreach(["центр25", "25центр", "0str"] as $str){

    $data = preg_split("/(\d+)/",$str, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);   
    print_r(array_filter($data));    
}
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => центр
    [1] => 25
)
Array
(
    [1] => 25
    [2] => центр
)
Array
(
    [2] => str
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте отрицание.

```
<?php

print_r(divide_sample('центр25'));

function divide_sample($sample_number)
{
    preg_match("/([^\d]+)(\d+)/", $sample_number, $pieces);

    return [$pieces[1], $pieces[2]];
}
```

http://tpcg.io/aZUPLO

В вашем варианте не находится ничего потому что регулярки не понимают уникод если это явно не запрошено. Например, такая регулярка с флагом `u` будет работать как вы хотите:

```
/([a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+)([0-9]+)/u
```

Comment: Кто ж виноват что вы поторопились?.. Если вы хотите знать позицию цифр и текста, то вам нужны две регулярки. Вторая делается легко перестановкой частей из первой.

Comment: Мне-то не нужно, это у автора вопроса такое требование :Р

Comment: Автор сам не понимает чего хочет. Проще две регулярки сделать, чем пытаться угадать что первое цифры, а что второе буквы.

Answer (score 1):

> Может есть другие варианты - не регулярные выражения?

```
function divide_sample($sample_number)
{
    $str = trim($sample_number, '1234567890');
    if ($str == '') {
        return [$sample_number, ''];
    } else if (($pos = strpos($sample_number, $str)) === 0) {
        return [$str, substr($sample_number, strlen($str))];
    } else {
        return [substr($sample_number, 0, $pos), substr($sample_number, $pos)];
    }
}

foreach (["центр25", "25центр", "0str", "256", "центр", "25str25"] as $str) {
    print_r(divide_sample($str));  
}
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => центр
    [1] => 25
)
Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => центр
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => str
)
Array
(
    [0] => 256
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => центр
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 25
    [1] => str25
)
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2e9fb1afb528033ea4a7ed43941c0c6a8ed4fbe

Answer (score 0):

А если вот так?

```
print_r(divide_sample('центр25'));

function divide_sample($sample_number)
{
    return preg_split('/(,?\s+)|((?<=[а-яa-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[а-яa-z]))/ui', $sample_number);
}
```

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что на  `центр25` оно не сработает

Comment: зачем маленькие и большие буквы, если можно регистронезависимый поиск сделать?